# Add redirection with regular expression on WordPress Site from .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to add redirection on the WordPress site from the .htaccess file

Current URL:

```
example.com/papaya-exfoliator/?uf
```

It will be redirected to

```
example.com/produit/papaya-exfoliator/
```

Currently, the "All In One Redirection" plugin is installed and it's working fine without regular expression.

Like if I hit `example.com/papaya-exfoliator` then it will redirect to `example.com/produit/papaya-exfoliator/` but if there are any extra data in the URL like `/?uf` then the redirection is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to redirect from `/papaya-exfoliator/?uf` to `/produit/papaya-exfoliator/`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uf$
RewriteRule ^(papaya-exfoliator)/?$ /produit/$1/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^(papaya-exfoliator)/?$`) matches against the URL-path only. You need to use an additional *condition* (ie. `RewriteCond` directive) to match against the query string (ie. `uf`).

I've made the trailing slash on the source URL optional since you used both versions (with and without the trailing slash) in your question.

The `QSD` flag is necessary in order to remove the query string from the target URL (otherwise it is copied by default). The `QSD` flag requires Apache 2.4. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then you will need to append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string instead (to essentially append an empty query string). eg. `/produit/$1/?`.

The `$1` backreference simply saves repetition by capturing `papaya-exfoliator` from the requested URL.

---

If you wish to redirect regardless of whether the query string is present or not then simply remove the `RewriteCond` directive. This then makes the rule in the *WP plugin* superfluous.

---

If you wish to redirect only when a query string is present (*any* query string) then change the `RewriteCond` directive to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

ie. It matches 1 character in the query string, so there is a query string on the requested URL.